# How can a swordsmen sword be pointed towards a target and follow it when using planet gravity in unity 3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this. I am trying to get an enemy swordsman to follow my player and aim the sword towards me but I can't seem to understand why it doesn't work and spazz's out(it works without the weapon pointing code)

```
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Follow(target);
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + transform.TransformDirection(moveDir) * walkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        AimTowards();
    }

    public void Follow(Transform target)
    {
        Vector3 targetVector = target.position - transform.position;
        float speed = (targetVector.magnitude) * 5;
        Vector3 directionVector = targetVector.normalized * speed;

        directionVector = Quaternion.Inverse(transform.rotation) * directionVector;
        moveDir = new Vector3(directionVector.x, directionVector.y, directionVector.z).normalized;
    }
    void AimTowards()
    {
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(moveDir.y, moveDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        pivot.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle - 90, Vector3.down);
    }
```

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5ism.png)

Here is a video of it https://vimeo.com/364530113

Here is a video of it without the aiming https://vimeo.com/364530129

Here is a video when using lookat instead (it gets weird) https://vimeo.com/364530148

Comment: `speed = (targetVector.magnitude) * 5`? This doesn't make sense to me, why should an enemy move faster the further away it is from you?

Comment: @Draco18s It has to do with the want to make it so you have to be in constant action

Comment: Is this script attached to the sword or the enemy?

Comment: @c0d3d Ok, then why `targetVector.normalized`? You get the same result from those two lines as `targetVector * 5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Lookat()` is the perfect solution to this problem.

---

Given the following case is that a **sword** has a **pivot** and a **parent** that is able to move independently and a **target**. See example:

[image: Example]

On the pivot attach a very simple script that will ensure that the pivot will be looking at the target. Also, make sure that the sword goes forward on the **+Z axis**:

[image: Positive Z]

---

In the script on pivot write the following:

```
//Target object
public Transform target;
//Pivot object (in this case the object the script is attached to)
public Transform pivot;

//Might want to use Update() instead
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    //Simply look at the target
    pivot.LookAt(target);
}
```

The sword should point at the start no matter if the parent object rotates or translates.

---

Also, in your script:

```
Vector3 targetVector = target.position - transform.position;
float speed = (targetVector.magnitude) * 5;
Vector3 directionVector = targetVector.normalized * speed;
```

Can be simplified to:

```
Vector3 targetVector = target.position - transform.position;
float speed = 5.0f;
Vector3 directionVector = targetVector * speed;
```

Because normalizing changes the magnitude of the vector to 1, therefore, multiplying it by the true magnitude will make it so it was never normalized. As @Draco18s says, it won't ensure constant motion.